# Getting fatal error for iostream

Tags: c++, llvm, clang

I wanted to write a simple clang plug-in. So I just executed a `"PrintFunctionNames"` plug-in provided in llvm-clang. But when i tried to execute a command :

> " clang -cc1 -load ../../Debug+Asserts/lib/libPrintFunctionNames.so
>   -plugin print-fns some-input-file.c "

it gives me 1 fatal error :

```
fatal error: 'iostream.h' file not found
#include<iostream.h>
        ^
1 error generated.
```

I also tried using -I option providing a path for include directory of `'iostream'` but it's still gives me the same error.

I tried it like:

> 'clang++ -I//usr/include/c++/4.6 -cc1 -load
>   ../../../../Release+Asserts/lib/libPrintFunctionNames.so -plugin
>   print-fns ak.cpp '

So how do I make this work?

Answer (score 2):

Don't add .h at the end.

```
#include <iostream>
```

That should fix it.

Answer (score 2):

`iostream` belongs to C++ not C. So you should include it as

```
#include <iostream>
```

Additionally since you are programming in C++ you should name your source file ending with .cpp not .c to make it clear to the compiler and everyone else, that you want to use C++. Also you might need to invoke `clang++` in your first compiler call (but I am not sure about that in context of plugins)

Answer (score 1):

After the C++ language was standardized by the ISO, the header file named `iostream.h` was renamed to `iostream`. Change your program to use `#include <iostream>` instead and it should compile.

You will also need to add `using namespace std;` statement after each include (or prefix each reference to an iostream function/object with `std::`).

You can start by using this

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
```

Once you are more comfortable with namespaces, you can remove the `using` statement & instead either use `std::cout`, `std::cin` etc or have a

```
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
```

etc.

Answer (score 0):

I meet the same question,

- template.cpp

```
g++ template.cpp
```

```
compare<int>com1(3,7);
```

1. List item

```
compare<double>com2(12.34,56.78); 
compare<char>com3('a','x'); 
cout<<",the max value:"<<com1.max()<<endl;   
cout<<",the max value:"<<com2.max()<<endl;
cout<<",the max value:"<<com3.max()<<endl;
return  0;
```

the question is up code segment composing not OK, use the shift + table typing next time.